# What is the difference between BindProperty and SetProperty on IModelBinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I'm creating a custom model binder in an Mvc application and I want to parse a string to an enumeration value and assign it to the model property. I have got it working overriding the `BindProperty` method, but I also noticed that there is a `SetProperty` method.

```
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        switch (propertyDescriptor.Name)
        {
            case "EnumProperty":
                BindEnumProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext);
                break;
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }

    private static void BindEnumProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var formValue = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["formValue"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(formValue))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var model = (MyModel)bindingContext.Model;
        model.EnumProperty = (EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), formValue);
    }
```

I’m not sure what the difference is between the two and whether I am doing this in the recommended way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, BindProperty is not a part of IModelBinder but, a protected method in DefaultModelBinder. You can access it only if you are sub-classing the DefaultModelBinder.

The following points should answer your question:

- BindProperty uses the IModelBinder
  interface it gets from the
  PropertyType of the
  propertyDescriptor argument. This
  allows you to inject custom
  properties into the property
  metadata.
- BindProperty properly
  handles validation. It (also) calls the
  SetProperty method only if the
  new value is valid.

So if you want proper validation (using the annotation attributes)  you must definitely call BindProperty. By calling SetProperty you bypass all the built-in validation mechanisms.

You should check out the source code of [DefaultModelBinder](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Web/System/Web/Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs.htm) the see what each method does, since the intellisense provides only limited information.

Comment: Source is now at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs

Comment: @Rob Your URL is invalid also

Comment: @Kilanny, invalid how? It still seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think SetProperty takes actual value to set as the last parameter.