# MVC3 IModelBinder and updating member data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class like this

```
public class Position
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to use a textarea to accept phone numbers as one per line. After that the model obviously doesn't bind correctly, so I found `IModelBinder` that can help with this, but I don't see how I can inject the transformed data back into the model.

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
     var phones = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("phones");
     var values = phones.AttemptedValue;

     var phoneList = ..... //split and stuff

     //now what? how to set it back?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class `PhoneNumberList` and use that instead of `IEnumerable<string>` in your model. Then you can create a custom model binder for `PhoneNumberList` by copying the existing code. Binding your existing model type `Position` will be otherwise unaffected.

Alternatively (but a more complex solution) - you can preserve the existing definition of `IEnumerable<string>`. You would subclass the `DefaultModelBinder` and examine the `PropertyMetadata` of any `IEnumerable<string>` property. If it contains some identifying metadata that you have added (e.g. via an attribute) then it could perform your custom binding, otherwise it reverts to the base binding.

As an aside - you could also consider using `bindingContext.ModelName` instead of hard-coding the value provider key to "phones":

```
var phones = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
```

Comment: The more complex solution is basically what I was looking for - but I couldn't find an example of converting and re-saving as different type with BindProperty

Comment: You don't need to save as a different type, the property's type remains as IEnumerable<string> - you just create a List<string> in the binder and assign that.

Comment: So in my binder I should cast `bindingContext.Model` to my model and then take the value from Request.Form, transform and assign to the casted model?

Comment: Take a look at DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245643/what-is-the-difference-between-bindproperty-and-setproperty-on-imodelbinder for some background (sorry, I'm a bit busy to create an example just now).

Comment: Yep, looks like that poster does it exactly like I described, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of your model, populate its properties and return it. Thats it.

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
     var phones = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("phones");
     var values = phones.AttemptedValue;

     var phoneList = ..... //split and stuff
//IE
    Position position = new Postion();
    position.PhoneNumbers = phoneList;
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Yep, problem with that is I want to customize only one field, while I have lots of others that are mapped correctly.